# fabric.js 1.4.0 - How can I get animation and gestures support?

Tags: fabricjs

it seems as if there is something missing in the current fabric.js version (1.4.0): When I use the version from github, the support for gestures is missing. When I download a custom buid from the fabric.js website, I get gestures support, but the animation functions are missing. I tried to load both version, but gestures are still not working.

Does anyone have a current fabric.js version that supports both, animation and gestures?

Comment: I found no solution for this yet. Am I doing something wrong? In the complete(?) version from Github the comment at the biginning of the code says "modules=ALL exclude=gestures,cufon,json minifier=uglifyjs".
How can I get and use the gesture module? I tried loading the gesture mixin, but this didn't work. I really need to get this working. Any help is really really appreciated.

Comment: I got gestures to work with an older fabric release. Unfortunately the documentation for eventlisteners on gestures is not satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own custom build.

As per [fabric.js documentation](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js#building) clone the repository on your pc and type (assuming node.js is already installed):

```
node build.js modules=ALL
```

to get a full featured fabric.js source in `dist/fabric.js`